# Deletion of nodes with Graphviz as library

Tags: c++, graphviz

I am using graphviz as a library in C++. I use it to layout my graph, e.g. calculate positions of nodes and edges, but do the rendering myself.

My question concerns the deletion of nodes and their effect on adjacent edges. Unfortunately none of the documentation provided on the graphviz homepage addresses this question. It was implicitly asked in this post ([Questions about Graphviz API (Graphviz as a library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734936/questions-about-graphviz-api-graphviz-as-a-library)) but not answered either. I hope to find answers here.

I have:
Agraph_t* myGraph and one of it's nodes as Agnode_t* myNode.
When I use agdelnode(myGraph, myNode), what happens to the edges adjacent to myNode? Are they deleted or detatched from their head/tail?

And what does the return type of agdelnode (also agdeledge and agclose) mean? My guess is that it indicates the function's success with (0 = succesfull) and (every other value = error occurred).

Comment: Could you answer your question in a new Answer or in a comment to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I use agdelnode(myGraph, myNode), what happens to the edges adjacent to myNode? Are they deleted or detatched from their head/tail?

All edges adjacent to myNode will be deleted and their memory freed.

> And what does the return type of agdelnode (also agdeledge and agclose) mean? My guess is that it indicates the function's success with (0 = succesfull) and (every other value = error occurred).

The returned value is either SUCCESS, if the memory of the node was successfully freed or FAILURE, if not.

This is my interpretation of the [source code](http://www.graphviz.org/pub/graphviz/development/doxygen/html/node_8c_source.html) (link taken from Tim Biegeleisen's answer).

Answer (score -2):

Here is the source code for `agdelnode()` which I took from [this](http://www.graphviz.org/pub/graphviz/development/doxygen/html/node_8c_source.html) site.  You can read through it and answer your question.

```
int agdelnode(Agraph_t * g, Agnode_t * n) {
  Agedge_t *e, *f;

  if (!agfindnode_by_id(g, AGID(n)))
    return FAILURE; /* bad arg */

    if (g == agroot(g)) {
      for (e = agfstedge(g, n); e; e = f) {
        f = agnxtedge(g, e, n);
        agdeledge(g, e);
      }

      if (g->desc.has_attrs)
        agnodeattr_delete(n);

      agmethod_delete(g, n);
      agrecclose((Agobj_t *) n);
      agfreeid(g, AGNODE, AGID(n));
    }

    if (agapply (g, (Agobj_t *) n, (agobjfn_t) agdelnodeimage, NILnode, FALSE) == SUCCESS) {
      if (g == agroot(g))
        agfree(g, n); 

      return SUCCESS;

   } else
       return FAILURE;
}
```